# Use of \tikzset{xyplane/.estyle={cm={a,b,c,d,(e,f)}}}

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I try to imitate [this](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103wolcott.pdf) paper and get troubles projecting things in the xyplane.

Rotation matrix around x axis with an angle a is :

[1,0]

[0,cos(a)]

But if a=pi/2, this matrix is equal to :

[1,0]

[0,0]

and `\tikzset{xyplane/.estyle={cm={1,0,0,0,(0,0)}}}` won't work. How to deal with that ?

PS : Is it possible to use Latex in a post ? My matrices are very, very ugly...

PS2 : Does anyone know the automatics angles that `tikz-3dplot` apply to the `\tdplotsetmaincoords{ax}{az}` when we don't use this command. I mean, if we use `\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}` and plot a basis, the z axis is invisible because it is perpendicular to the screen but if we don't use `\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}` and plot a basis, the z axis is visible. What's are the anges ax and az to apply to get the same result ? Equivalently : what system {a,b,c,d,(e,f)} is used. Not sure I'm clear...

Thanks in advance

Comment: `\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}` does not come from TikZ but from `tikz-3dplot`. It is an external package.

Comment: Yes it's true, I just add the tag, thanks. But my troubles remains unresolved.

Comment: Please provide a small compilable example (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that uses the commands you are asking about. This makes it easier to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm so ashamed, it was just a tikzlibrary I forgot to add to my document. Tikz indicate me the line of the tikset so I immediately suppose the reason was the singular matrix... Surprisingly my document compiled without de tikzlibrary until this moment. Thank you @Marijn. I didn't provide MWE because I was really SURE that mas the matrix :(...

Comment: @kipgon don't feel bad about it, all of us have forgotten trivial things like adding tikzlibraries at some point - I know I have :)

Comment: If you want to know what a transformation by `tikz-3dplot` does, you could do `\pgfgettransform{\mytrafo} \typeout{\mytrafo}` inside the `tikzpicture` / `scope`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the right formula. The formula you have is the 2x2 part of the rotation matrix Rx for 3D space. `cm` key rotates 2D points. Hence if you rotate `xy` plane around `x` 90 degrees its `y` component disappears. Thus there is nothing wrong so far.

If you want rotation in the `xy` plane then you need to rotate around the hypothetical `z` axis and that is given by

```
[ cos(a) sin(a)]*[x] + [xshift] = [xnew]
[-sin(a) cos(a)] [y]   [yshift]   [ynew]
```

In terms of the related `cm` values this is

```
cm={cos(a),sin(a),-sin(a),cos(a),{(xshift,yshift)}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @percusse, that was just a stupid mistake of mine. See my comment above.